# C# string keep turning null while trying to use recursion function

Tags: c#, recursion

I've got an assanigment in my course to write a recursive function that will display the signs '%' And '#' alternate by the number that the user has enterd.
so if i say the the user entered the number 5, the outcome will be like this: '%#%#%'.

i think i have most of the work done. the only problem i have at the moment is that the string that i have to show the signs keeps turning 'null' with each iteration that the function makes.

this is my code:

```
public static string ShowGibrish(int num)
{
    string s="";
    while (num!=0)
    {
        if (num % 2 == 0)
        {
            s = s+ "%";
            ShowGibrish(num - 1);
        }
        else if (num % 2 != 0)
        {
            s =s+ "#";
            return ShowGibrish(num - 1);
        }

    }
    return s;
}
```

other student used stringbuilder to make the string to show, and used another private function and called it with the public function. but i think my code could work also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
public static string ShowGibberish(int num)
{
    if (num == 0) { return ""; }
    else {
         if (num % 2 == 0) {return "%" + ShowGibberish(num-1);}
         else {return "#" + ShowGibberish(num-1);}
    }
}
```

Your code mixes an iterative and recursive approach. Use one or the other only to solve this cleanly.

Comment: You are correct but since this is their homework assignment I don't think you should provide code.

Comment: Nice short implementation, just for neatness ShowGibrish is spelled in two different ways, maybe correct it?

Comment: @Alex Rosenfeld Thank you, it's not like my code but it works!

Answer (score 1):

First problem you have is that you declare a new string at the start of the method, but you never transport that string into the recursive function meaning you lose all progress from the concatenation.

Second problem is you have a while loop for some reason, as far as I know its not needed here.

1. Start by adding an optional parameter to the function: `string s = ""`.
2. Remove the while loop, its not needed
3. The first thing you should do is check if `num` is 0 or not, and return s if it is.
4. Modify s based on your odd/even logic
5. Then return the result of the recursive call `ShowGibrish(num - 1, s)`

I removed the code because I didn't catch the homework part.

Comment: Thank you for the explantion!  trust me man i dont know what happend there. One teacher teaches one way, and other teacher tells you 'no, it's should be like that' i dont know what they want anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem lies in your while loop. What is occurring is each instance of the function on the stack is executing a while loop instead of the looping being solely handled by recursion. Each instance of the function should only execute if the base case != 0 as opposed to while the base case != 0.

Variables are scoped to their respective functions and so in the current state of your code the value that the while loop is evaluating never can reach 0.

Sorry I'm not going to provide code for you since it is an assignment.